# Modified Periodogram function in MATLAB

Tags: power-spectral-density, window-functions

Given below is a function written in MATLAB for computing the modified periodogram, taken from Hayes, Statistical Digital Signal Processing and Modeling

```
function Px = mper(x, win, n1, n2)

x = x(:);
if nargin == 2
    n1 = 1; n2 = length(x);
end

N = n2 - n1 + 1;

switch win
    case 1
        w = rectwin(N);
    case 2 
        w = hamming(N);
    case 3
        w = hanning(N);
    case 4
        w = bartlett(N);
    case 5
        w = blackman(N);
end;

xw = x(n1:n2).*w/norm(w);
Px = N*mypdg(xw);
```

Can anyone explain what is going on in second last line of the code
`xw = x(n1:n2).*w/norm(w)`

Is dividing by norm necessary to compute `xw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's explicitly necessary to normalize the periodogram for non-rectangular windows. However I cannnot see the **mypdg** script in the book ?

From Monson Hayes's book *Statistical Digital Signal Processing and Modeling* , chapter 8 (spectrum estimation), Section 8.2.3 (modified periodogram), equations 8.49

$$ \boxed{ \hat{P}_M(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1}{NU} \left| \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(n)~ w(n) ~ e^{-j\omega n} \right|^2 }$$

and 8.50

$$ \boxed{ U = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |w(n)|^2 }$$

define the scaling to correct the biasing of the periodogram estimate due to using nonrectangular windows.

Note that in the program **norm** is used during windowing stage before the FFT, so that after FFT and squaring, you will get norm square which is identical to $U$ above.

Comment: I forgot to mention, mypdg is the `periodogram` function given in the book. I changed the name to mypdg

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the equation involving the use of norm or cite the explanation from the book?